# Is Gilles the highest ranked unix.stackexchange user?

Tags: discussion, users

Is [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) the highest ranked unix.stackexchange user?

His page says he is in the top 0.02%. Is there someone in the top 0.01%?

Is there some way for querying for this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gilles is the top user by reputation. See [the list of users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) ordered by reputation.

Comment: I've got some catching up to do, and so do you :)